# IE8 / IE7 Styling a Button Problems (screenshot attached)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to create a button [(Here's a screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDui6.jpg) that would be cross-browser compliant.
[image]

on IE10 and IE9 it looks ok.

Main problems:

1. **IE8:** added an ie8 class to create the red arrow, Is the code in the `HEAD` written right? since I want both to have the html5shiv (for other needs) on any IE9 and below,
   but for this specific button I want to have a special class in order to draw the arrow.
   can these two lines go together?

HEAD:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

2. **IE8:** When I delete the `.aaa` from: `.ie8 .aaa .button1{padding-right:4px;width:94px}`,
   it screws up the padding, making it wider on the left. I have no clue why, as the class `aaa` does not exist in the html at all.
3. **IE7:** is there a way to make a similar appearance for IE7?
4. Any other comments about perhaps a better practice to do this?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="a.htm" method="POST" target="_blank">
<div class="button-holder"><input type="submit" class="button1" value="Hello">
<span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.button-holder {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.button1 {
    padding: 4px 30px 4px 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.arrow:after {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.arrow:before {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
margin-top: 6px;
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
height: 11px;
top: 6px;
right: 10px;
width: 3px;}

.button1 {
border-style: solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background-color: #FFE76E;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#F90,#FC0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 100.00%, 50.00% 0.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(255,198,1,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(255,248,162,1.00)));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F90 0,#FC0 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,198,1,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,248,162,1.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255,198,1,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,248,162,1.00) 100%);
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color: #003!important;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
border: 0;}

.button1:hover, .button1:focus {
    background-color: #FFC808;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#F90,#FC0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 100.00%, 50.00% 0.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(237,162,0,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(255,234,93,1.00)));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F90 0,#FC0 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(237,162,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,234,93,1.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(237,162,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,234,93,1.00) 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
}


.ie8 .aaa .button1{padding-right:4px;width:94px}
.ie8 .arrow:before,.ie8 .arrow:after{background-color:transparent}
.ie8 .arrow:after { 
font-size:40px;
font-size:4rem;
content:"›";
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
line-height:11px;
text-indent:-5px;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: IE7 does not support pseudo elements...use an image instead?

Comment: What does `.aaa` do then and why is it in you CSS?

Comment: It came from some piece of code I've found. here it doesn't do anything, yet still effects the padding for some reason. I guess the line isn't written right somewhere.

Comment: If it's supposed to add padding to the button it should be `.aaa.button1` (no space)

Comment: left side of screenshot is IE8 with current code, it's ok. right side is when I take it off. I want to delete `aaa` yet still have it look like the left side.

Comment: What do you expect your button to look like in IE7 when it doesn't support box-shadow, border-radius, linear-gradient, transforms, or pseudo elements?  If you *need* these things, a simple search for "ie7 gradient" would give you the answer you need.

Comment: @cimmanon that's not the main subject of the question, questions 1+2 do not refer to IE7.

Comment: @user3406294 Really? "IE7: is there a way to make a similar appearance for IE7?"

Comment: @cimmanon that's only one third of the question.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't ask 3 questions?  I don't know what point you're trying to make here.  IE7 doesn't support the properties you're using, you would have known that if you'd done some research before asking (you probably would have found reasonable fallbacks, if they exist).  If IE7 is not an important part of your question, then why mention it?

Comment: @cimmanon since the width of the button in IE7 is wider. this is something that might be fixed. I didn't ask to make it gradient as well. I've asked to make it similar as possible - width wise as well.

Answer (score 0):

for border radius and box shadow you can try this : http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/